# I have issues running a bot using Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, command, bots

so I am trying to run a program using `python bot.py` but it doesn't seem to work. I get this problem:

```
C:\Users\.\OneDrive\Skrivbord\provbokning_trafikverket-master>python bot.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57492/devtools/browser/9d9aaac2-d781-446f-bdda-c4841ac30423
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\.\OneDrive\Skrivbord\provbokning_trafikverket-master\bot.py", line 108, in <module>
    find_exam(SeleniumDriver())
  File "C:\Users\.\OneDrive\Skrivbord\provbokning_trafikverket-master\bot.py", line 85, in find_exam
    for i in config.locations:
AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'locations'

C:\Users\.\OneDrive\Skrivbord\provbokning_trafikverket-master>[25264:23336:0202/151259.845:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[25264:23336:0202/151259.845:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
[25264:23336:0202/151259.845:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(235)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[25264:11404:0202/151259.853:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:12:59.850] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: En enhet som õr ansluten till datorn fungerar inte. (0x1F)
[25264:11404:0202/151259.854:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:12:59.852] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: En enhet som õr ansluten till datorn fungerar inte. (0x1F)
[25264:11404:0202/151259.854:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [15:12:59.853] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: En enhet som õr ansluten till datorn fungerar inte. (0x1F)
[25264:23336:0202/151259.870:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(239)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()
[22920:20892:0202/151455.764:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(454)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

The bot I am trying to run is from [here](https://github.com/Daky60/provbokning_trafikverket). This is the code in bot.py:

```
social_security = '19941024-xxxx'
license_type = 'B'
exam = 'Körprov'
rent_or_language = 'Manuell bil'
dates = ['2022-02-04', '2022-02-20']
locations = ['Sollentuna']
```

Here is the code for bot.py:
https://github.com/Daky60/provbokning_trafikverket/blob/master/bot.py

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @Prophet Do you mean this one? ''social_security = '19941024-xxxx'
license_type = 'B'
exam = 'Körprov'
rent_or_language = 'Manuell bil'
dates = ['2022-02-04', '2022-02-20']
locations = ['Sollentuna']''

Comment: No. You are presenting only some variables initialization. Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: @Prophet That's the only code I edited to suit my need because it had variables, it's called the config.py in the github link. The other is bot.py, if you want that code, I will edit it into the original post, at the bottom.

Comment: OK, now I understand.